# Modify strings in executable with GDB

Tags: gdb

I have an ELF file that has certain strings in it that I would like to modify (they are paths to configuration directories). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19899814/1953537) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19895035/1953537) says something about running `gdb --write <path_to_executable>` to modify a string in `<path_to_executable>`, but does not go into further detail. What are the other things that I need to do with that command to accomplish my goal?

Comment: @EmployedRussian Nope. Not a duplicate. I was asking about a specific method that that question's answer does not cover.

Answer (score 1):

(There are some binary editing tools better than gdb, any hex edit program or some reverse engineering tools)

`-write` option of `gdb` is documented in the documentation of the gdb: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Mode-Options.html#Mode-Options

> `-write`
>
> Open the executable and core files for both reading and writing. This is equivalent to the ‘set write on’ command inside GDB (see Patching).

Patching is link to https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Patching.html#Patching

> 17.6 Patching Programs
>
> ...
>   If you’d like to be able to patch the binary, you can specify that explicitly with the `set write` command. For example, you might want to turn on internal debugging flags, or even to make emergency repairs.
>
> `set write on`
>   `set write off`
>   If you specify ‘set write on’, GDB opens executable and core files for both reading and writing; if you specify `set write off` (the default), GDB opens them read-only.
>
> If you have already loaded a file, you must load it again (using the `exec-file` or `core-file` command) after changing `set write`, for your new setting to take effect.
>
> `show write`
>   Display whether executable files and core files are opened for writing as well as reading.

Still no information about file editing. Just try memory editing command `set something=value`, where something is the address with correct type, use addresses of your strings (like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/3305200):

https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Assignment.html#Assignment

> To store values into arbitrary places in memory, use the ‘{…}’ construct to generate a value of specified type at a specified address (see Expressions). For example, {int}0x83040 refers to memory location 0x83040 as an integer (which implies a certain size and representation in memory), and
>
> ```
> set {int}0x83040 = 4
> ```
>
> stores the value 4 into that memory location.

Comment: Just tried: file editing with gdb and `-write` does not work when target binary is running; and when it does not running (and not started), with address from `info file`, it is still unchanged and `gdb` crashed into corefile on `quit`. Feel some concerns about (rebuilding gdb with debugging information in gdb format and) debugging gdb with gdb (or with valgrind: "address 0x28 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd .. of signal 11 (SIGSEGV) .. Access not within mapped region at address 0x28")... Seems that `gdb -write` does not work for years at all, even without editing commands used.

Comment: The error is from `bfd_close -> _bfd_elf_write_obejct_contents -> _bfd_elf_assign_file_positions_for_non_load -> _bfd_elf_strtab_finalize` (last is in `elf-strtab.c`) probably because _bfd_elf_strtab_finalize was called with NULL `tab`, and bug report is https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=835439 and https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=20948: "jbm 2017-06-01 10:14:34 UTC: This is a null-ptr dereference in bfd/elf-strtab.c:367, resulting from a null-ptr stringtab extracted in bfd/elf.c:6272. `elf_shstrtab(abfd) == abfd->tdata.elf_obj_data->o->strtab_ptr == NULL`